# Is there any way to check that uploaded file is mp3 or not in server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to do that? And also how to extract metadata from it (idv3 tag and etc).

Comment: In what server? how do you uploaded it? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), an mp3 file begins with the following magic numbers (bytes):

0xFF, 0xFB

or

0x49, 0x44, 0x33